# npm node-gyp build error CentOS

Tags: node.js, npm, centos, node-gyp

I am installing npm install on my CentOS machine and it gives the following error again and again. I have installed all latest dev-tools

I also tried downgrading and upgrading but the issue remains the same. I am using CentOS6 on Amazon AWS.

```
npm WARN engine node-stringprep@0.7.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12"} (current: {"node":"4.4.7","npm":"2.15.8"})

> node-stringprep@0.7.3 install /root/NodeJSCID/node_modules/node-stringprep
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
make: Entering directory `/root/NodeJSCID/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_stringprep/node-stringprep.o
In file included from ../node-stringprep.cc:1:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)’
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:256:25: error: ‘template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)’ previously declared here
 NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                         ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:13: error: ‘node::smalloc’ has not been declared
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘callback’
     , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:50: error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                  ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:665:60: error: ‘hint’ was not declared in this scope
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, length, callback, hint);
                                                            ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded ‘New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)’ is ambiguous
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
                                                                   ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:25:0,
                 from ../node-stringprep.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:25:0,
                 from ../node-stringprep.cc:1:
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘node::encoding’
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
 NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                        ^
/root/.node-gyp/4.4.7/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
In file included from ../node-stringprep.cc:1:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert ‘node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))’ from ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Object>’
     return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), size);
                                                             ^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)’:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:683:12: error: ‘Use’ is not a member of ‘node::Buffer’
     return node::Buffer::Use(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
            ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_stringprep/node-stringprep.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/NodeJSCID/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/NodeJSCID/node_modules/node-stringprep
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-stringprep@0.7.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-stringprep@0.7.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-stringprep package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-stringprep
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-stringprep
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/NodeJSCID/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The versions of gcc and python in CentOS 6 (and all the other RHEL 6.x derivatives) isn't recent enough to support compiling modules with the version of node you're using. If you need to use node-gyp you'll need to downgrade to a version of node < 4, or install SCL & devtoolset-3, then enable them before doing npm install.

Its misleading since they added a repo for recent node versions on EL6, but they don't work out of the box if you need to compile anything.

Edit: 
To clarify on devtoolset-3, you'll need to install `centos-release-scl-rh`, `devtoolset-3-gcc-c++`, `devtoolset-3-binutils`, & `python27`. Enable devtoolset-3 (`/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/enable`) and python 2.7 (`/opt/rh/python27/enable`). You should then be able to do npm install successfully. Enabling these guys only lasts for the length of your shell session, so you'll need to do it every time you log in or add it to your bash profile.

Comment: I installed it and enabled it but its not working still giving compile error

Comment: Please note that the problem is with this version of CentOS only. The CentOS 7 with 2015 GCC is perfectly working with this

Comment: Be aware that `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash` is valid for the current terminal session only. When / if you exit the terminal you will have the default gcc/g++ version 4.4.7 again.